# How can I prove that $p(x)=x^4+x+1$ doesn't have real roots?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quartics

> Let $p(x)=x^4+x+1$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. How can I prove that $p$ doesn't have real roots?

#### My attempt:

From calculus, I know that

$$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} p(x) = \infty\,.$$

Then, if it has real roots, then we have two or four real roots. I know that if $$\gcd \left( p(x), p'(x) \right) = 1\,,$$ then the roots is simple. Is there another hint?

Comment: "Then, if it has real roots we have two or four real roots." -- Minor correction on this point, but this isn't necessarily true. For instance, $f(x)=(x-1)^2$ has only one root, $x=1$, because it "sits" on the $x$-axis. $f$ might only have real roots, but they're also not distinct ... so I guess it's a matter of convention/preference as to how you count them. It might be worth being clear on such details due to such ambiguities.

Comment: They are "usually" counted with multiplicity though: a lot of the theorems (e.g. the corollary of the FTA that states that an nth degree polynomial has n roots and Bezout's theorem) are stated using multiplicity in order to simplify their statements. IMO, that should be the default interpretation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider three cases . . .

- If $x\ge 0$ then
  $
  x^4+x+1\ge 1
  $.$\\[4pt]$

  If $-1 < x < 0$ then
  $
  x^4+x+1 > x^4 + (-1) + 1 > 0
  $.$\\[4pt]$

  If $x\le -1$ then
  $
  x^4+x+1 
  \ge
  x^2+x+1 
  =
  \Bigr(x+\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^2+\frac{3}{4}
  $.

Thus in all three cases, $x^4+x+1$ is positive.

It follows that $x^4+x+1$ has no real roots.

Comment: if $x \leq -1$   then $x^4 \geq |x|,$  so $x^4 + x \geq 0$

Comment: Yes, that's a nice way to dispatch that case.

Answer (score 26):

If $x$ is a real number, then $$x^4+x+1=\left(x^2-\frac12\right)^2+\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac12>0\,.$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $p'(x)=4x^3+1$ has one root $c$ (to see this, remark that $p"(x)\geq 0$), if $x<c, p'(c<0,$ if $x>c, p'(c>0$, show that $p(c)>0$. The function decreases from $-\infty$ to $c$ and increases from $c$ to $+\infty$.

Comment: check your $p'$ calculation. Leading coefficient is...?

Comment: I know that $p'$ has one real root, it is given by $\frac{-1}{\sqrt[3]{4}}$, but honestly I don't know how it solves my question..

Comment: Show that $p(root)>0$

Comment: It's easy, $\frac{-1}{\sqrt[3]{4}}< 1$ then $(\frac{-1}{\sqrt[3]{4}})^4 + \frac{-1}{\sqrt[3]{4}} +1$ is positive...But how can I conclude that?

Comment: in your sum, you have $1$, a positive term and a negative term inferior to $1$

Comment: That doesn't answer the question: $q(x)=p(x)-1$ has the same derivative but real roots.

Answer (score 4):

$$p := x^4 + x + 1 = \begin{bmatrix} x^2\\ x\\ 1\end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -t\\ 0 & 2 t & 0.5\\ -t & 0.5 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x^2\\ x\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

where $t \in \Bbb R$. Using [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), we learn that the (symmetric) matrix above is **positive semidefinite** for $t = 0.5$. Using the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition),

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -0.5\\ 0 & 1 & 0.5\\ -0.5 & 0.5 & 1\end{bmatrix} = {\rm L} {\rm L}^\top$$

where

$${\rm L} = \begin{bmatrix} \color{blue}{1} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & \color{magenta}{1} & 0\\ \color{blue}{-\frac{1}{2}} & \color{magenta}{\frac{1}{2}} & \color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$

and, thus,

$$p = \left( \color{blue}{x^2 - \frac12} \right)^2 + \left( \color{magenta}{x + \frac12} \right)^2 + \left( \color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} \right)^2 > 0$$

which is the exact same **sum of squares** (SOS) decomposition in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3786765/339790).

---

#### [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org) code

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> t = symbols('t', real=True)
>>> M = Matrix([[ 1,   0,  -t],
                [ 0, 2*t, 1/2],
                [-t, 1/2,   1]])
>>> L = M.subs(t,1/2).cholesky()
>>> L
Matrix([
[   1,   0,         0],
[   0,   1,         0],
[-1/2, 1/2, sqrt(2)/2]])
```

---

#### Related

- [Writing $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 - 3 ( x^3 y + y^3 z + z^3 x)$ as a sum of two squares of quadratic forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2414847/339790)

---

[polynomials](/questions/tagged/polynomials) [sum-of-squares-method](/questions/tagged/sum-of-squares-method) [matrices](/questions/tagged/matrices) [matrix-decomposition](/questions/tagged/matrix-decomposition) [cholesky-decomposition](/questions/tagged/cholesky-decomposition)

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use AM-GM, like so:
$$x^4+1=x^4+\frac13+\frac13+\frac13\geqslant 4\sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4}{3^3}}\geqslant |x|\geqslant -x$$
$\implies x^4+x+1>0$ as the inequalities cannot be simultaneously equal.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

$$
p(x) p(-x) \;=\; x^8 + 2 x^4 - x^2 + 1 \;=\; x^8 + x^4 + \left(x^2 - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4} \;\gt\; 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

$x^4$ is positive except for $x = 0$.  $x + 1$ is positive for $x > -1$.  So the only possibility for the polynomial (the sum of those 2 parts) to be negative is for $x \le -1$.

But the polynomial is positive at $x = -1$ and $x^4$ grows much faster than $x + 1$ for $|x| > 1$ so the polynomial is positive everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

By studying $p'$ you easily see that $p$ is a decreasing function on $]-\infty, -1/\sqrt[3]{4}]$ and an increasing function on $[-1/\sqrt[3]{4},\infty[$. From that, you now that the minimal value $p(x)$ is $p(-1/\sqrt[3]{4})$ which is positive. Then $p$ has no real root.

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x) = 4x^3 +1$.

To find extreme points $f'(x) = 4x^3 + 1=0 \implies x =-\sqrt[3]{\frac 14}$

$f''(x) = 12x^2$ and $f''(-\sqrt[3]{\frac 14})= 12(-\sqrt[3]{\frac 14}) > 0$ so this is a minimum.

So $f(x) \ge f(-\sqrt[3]{\frac 14})= \sqrt[3]{\frac 1{4^4}} -\sqrt[3]{\frac 14} + 1  > -\sqrt[3]{\frac 14}_1 >-1+1 = 0$ for all $x$

Answer (score 0):

**Inconsistency of discriminants**

Let $r$ be any such real root. Then $x^4+x+1=r^2x^2+x+1=0$ at that root, and so the latter quadratic polynomial has that same real root $r$.

It follows that the discriminant of the quadratic must satisfy

$1-4r^2\ge0\implies|r|\le\frac12.$

So the proposed real root must be no greater than $\frac12$ in absolute value, but this is contradicted by the fact that $1>|x^4|+|x|$ for all of $\{x:|x|\le\frac12\}$.

As an aside, the contradiction step also rules out complex conjugate roots with absolute value $\le\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way

1. for $x> -1$

$$x^4+x+1>x^4\ge 0$$

2. for $x\le -1$ by $y=-\frac1{x}$ with $0<y\le 1$

$$x^4+x+1=\frac{y^4-y^3+1}{y^4}$$

and

$$y^4-y^3+1 \ge y^4-y^2+1\ge \frac34 $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$1)$ If $x\ge 0$, then $p(x)\ge 1\implies p(x)$ does not have any non negative root.

$2)$ For $x\ne \pm 1, 0$, A.M $\ge G.M$ gives $p(x)=x^4+x+1\gt 2x^2+x$

In view of $1)$ suppose that $x<0$.

Note that $2x^2+x\le 0\implies 2x+1\ge 0\implies x\ge-1/2$

It follows that $x^4+x+1\ge x^4+1/2>1/2\implies p(x)\ne 0$ for $x<0: 2x^2+x\le 0$.

And if $2x^2+x>0$, then by $2)$, it follows that $p(x)>0\implies p(x)\ne 0$.

It follows that $p$ has no real solutions.